# Calculating the distance traveled on vehicles based on odometer readings

Tags: mysql, sql, zoho

```
SELECT    
"Date",
"Vehicle Reg Number",
"ODO Meter Reading",
"Liters",
"Price Per Liter"    
FROM "Biz - Refuel Data"
```

So I want to find out what was the distance traveled of every vehicle before refueling.

With this we can Calculate the km traveled of our trucks.

Screenshot of our data.

Fuel Data

[image]

So to Create a Scenario.

The guys drive with a vehicle up and down like a sales rep.

They do a submission on our application called biz (its an web based app) every time they refuel.

The fill in info like:
Date, Time, GPS, Vehicle Reg, ODO Meter, Liters, Price per Liter

This we then pull over(HTML Link) to the Zoho Reports (Bi Tool) to pull some insights.
Here is the data Link.
https://www.bizeff.com/bizlive/Reports/DetailedSubmissionsExpanded/vertical.php?datepicker=2018-11-01&datepicker2=2018-12-04&user=All&site=All&job=Biz%20-%20ReFuel&comparison_item=

But each submission into the data will be one row at a time. so if 20 people submit this, we will have a collected data of all 20 truck/Vehicles combinde as per screenshot above.

We would like to use a ZOHO Query to work out the diffrence between the ODO meter to say that the rep traveled 400Km before refueling.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your source data contains multiple entries for same trucks, which corresponds to different refueling events, I might assume. So your resulting data set should contain aggregated data, like minimal/maximal mileage per vehicle per month, let say

Comment: Which DBMS is used to store that raw data? Is it Oracle, MySQL, MS SQL...?

Comment: MySQL and we pull the data Via a HTML link into Zoho Reports.

Comment: What happens in this data when a vehicle is refueled? How do we know how much fuel was added during that event? Please add more data if this is a scenario present in this data.

Comment: Something like `select month("Date") as "month", "Vehicle Reg Number", max("ODO Meter Reading") as "max ODO" from "Biz - Refuel Data" group by 1, 2` would show you maximum mileage per vehicle before refueling in each month

Comment: If you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick, it would give you the milage of each of the vehicles

```
select Vehicle Reg Number
     , max(ODO Meter Reading)-min(ODO Meter Reading))/sum(Liters) as Milage   
  from Biz - Refuel Data 
 group 
    by Vehicle Reg Number
```

Comment: I Used This 
select 
"Vehicle Reg Number", 
max("ODO Meter Reading")-min("ODO Meter Reading") as 'Milage'
from "Biz - Refuel Data" group by "Vehicle Reg Number"

But I need to pull the pervious submission from the latest. so not the min?